# Intercept private field access to do lazy loading

Tags: java, reflection, bytecode

I have a framework that load instances of arbitrary classes on behalf of a client and would like fields (specifically private fields) to initialize/load lazily only when fields are first accessed.

Is there a way to intercept such private field access and inject values into the field (possibly "cache" them aswell) before values are returned?

I guess java.lang.reflect.Proxy/InvocationHandler are ruled out since they are only capable of intercepting method calls.

I have a gut feeling that bytecode manipulation libraries can handle this. I have looked at ASM, Javassist, BCEL, cglib and searched all around but failed to find any clear instructions on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly doable with bytecode instrumentation using ASM or similar frameworks, but you will have to understand bytecode inner works as well as some JVM internals.

An easier approach would be to use AspectJ and apply aspects on your objects. There is somewhat similar example in this [AOSD'07 paper](http://aosd.net/2007/program/industry/I1-ClusteringJVMUsingAOP.pdf) about transparent clustering of Java objects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Im afraid aspectj does not work for me, since I would like to avoid compile time dependencies.